# Android Parse saveInBackground/subscribeInBackground not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

None of the Parse stuff happening in the background actually seems to be happening... I see all of the logs outside of the SaveCallback stuff, but nothing (not failure or success) from the callbacks.  Also, my installation never shows up in my Parse dashboard.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code (Parse related) in my Application file, in onCreate:

```
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "kladjlatkhdtlah", "akthjalhtdas");
    Log.d("com.parse", "Parse initialized");
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d("com.parse.push", "Should have subscribed");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully saved installation.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to save installation", e);
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d("com.parse.push", "Should have saved");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Comment: What's your SDK version? I had the same problem when I used some old SDKs, and only when the LocalDatastore is enable. Try to remove `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` and run your app again. I think the data would save to the server now.